# Button in if loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, if-statement

I'm working on a trivia code in javascript/html for a class i am taking, and when you press the correct button, i want an image of a check mark to show up.
Right now, for my check mark i am using the "opacity" trait:

```
<img id="checkOne" src="check.jpg" style="opacity: 0">
```

and then later i wanted to add that if you click the right button, the opacity would change from O to 1 (if you know a better way than this that's fine, I'm totally okay with changing that).

My question: How can i say "if *this* button is clicked, then change the opacity to 1/put this image on the webpage. *else* console log try again."
Help?
Also, here is an example of the html i have right now:

```
<p> where is the atacama desert located? </p>
<button class="southAmerica" data-image="checkOne">South America</button>
<button >Africa</button>
<button >Canada</button>
<button >Russia</button>
```

Comment: Can you show a representative snippet of your HTML, so we know what you're working with? And how are you identifying your 'correct button'?

Comment: You can use an event listener like this element.addEventListener('click', function() { /* do stuff here*/ }, false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the button, add an attribute that says which image it's associated with, e.g.

```
<button class="answerButton" data-image="checkOne">Button text</button>
```

Then in the click handler, you can get the value of this attribute and use it to modify the corresponding image:

```
var answerButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('answerButton');
for (var i = 0; i < answerButtons.length; i++) {
    answerButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var imageId = this.getAttribute('data-image');
        document.getElementById(imageId).style.opacity = 1;
    });
}
```

Comment: My question might be due to my being tired, or the question written ambiguously, but from my own reading it seems the user should click a button of some kind to trigger the image's opacity-change, rather than clicking the image itself.

Comment: I thought he was using the image as the button, but you're probably right. I've updated the answer.